# Selecting a second column with a SUM(SUM(value)) function

Tags: sql, sum, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a simple query trying to display the total of the totals for 12 periods. I am using a `SUM(SUM(value))` function to retrieve the data that I want, however, I am having a hard time displaying a second column in my result.

```
SELECT CENTRE, SUM(SUM(AMOUNT)) "TOTAL PAY" FROM AB
WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE 'N%' AND CENTRE = '2001' AND YEAR > 2015 GROUP BY AMOUNT, CENTRE;
```

The error that I am getting has to do with the grouping of the sentence.

[image]

Can you please tell me what I have done wrong. I have solved the problem with a sub-query, but I need to fix this query as well because it is used in a more advanced one as a sub-query.

Comment: why are you using two sum nested functions? what are you trying here?

Comment: Hello, I have amounts for 12 periods and I am trying to find the total of the 12 periods and display it per different centres of the department.
The first SUM finds out the total of all the accounts starting with N for each period. The second SUM is meant to display the total for the whole year.
The query works fine without the CENTRE column, but when I try and add it displays this error.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You might need a rollup, like:  SELECT CENTRE, SUM(AMOUNT) "TOTAL PAY" FROM AB WHERE ACCOUNT LIKE 'N%' AND CENTRE = '2001' AND YEAR > 2015 GROUP BY  CENTRE with rollup;

Comment: I think GROUP BY AMOUNT is a problem, should it be group by CENTRE only ?

Comment: Hello, yes I think I found the solution by removing the SUM(SUM(value)) and displaying it just by SUM(value) and grouping by CENTRE only. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is too vague to know for sure what you want. For example, what do you mean by "totals for 12 periods"? Is it that for `YEAR > 2015` you have 12 rows? Are you always having `CENTRE =` in your `WHERE` clause? If so, this might be what you want:

```
SELECT
    MAX(centre) "CENTRE",
    SUM(amount) "TOTAL PAY"
FROM
    ab
WHERE
        account LIKE 'N%'
    AND
        centre = '2001'
    AND
        year > 2015;
```

Or in case `CENTRE = 'smth'` might not be in your `WHERE` clause an you need total values for each CENTRE:

```
SELECT
    centre "CENTRE",
    SUM(amount) "TOTAL PAY"
FROM
    ab
WHERE
        account LIKE 'N%'
 /*   AND
        centre = '2001'*/
    AND
        year > 2015
GROUP BY
    centre;
```

Or in case for every (or one) CENTRE row you need to have total value of all centres:

```
SELECT
    "CENTRE",
    total "TOTAL PAY"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            centre,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY
                centre
                ORDER BY
                    0
            ) rn,
            SUM(
                amount
            ) OVER(PARTITION BY
                0
            ) total
        FROM
            ab
        WHERE
                account LIKE 'N%'
            AND
                year > 2015
    )
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give your solution a try. :)